# Rails sum method returns undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Generating the following error `undefined method +' for #<Debit`

where the controller action defines

```
@debits = Debit.order("vatunitid ASC").where('unit_id = ? AND folio_id = ?', session[:unit_id], @folio.id).to_a
@adhoc_folios = Folio.order("created_at asc").where(['checkout IS NULL AND unit_id = ? AND id != ?', session[:unit_id], @folio.id]).all
@vatunits = Vatunit.where(['unit_id = ?', session[:unit_id]]).to_a
@rates = @debits.map(&:vatunitid).uniq
```

and presently in the view (for testing purposes)

```
 @rates.each do |rate| 
   @debits_for_rate = @debits.select{ |i| i.vatunitid == rate } 
   @debits_for_rate.count 
   @debits_for_rate.sum(:amount)
```

The count instruction returns a proper value
The call to sum is deemed at this point inexistent.

How did this come about and how to overcome it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it in inefficient way by transforming AR into array and then performing Ruby operations while database level calculations could be used instead.

But to solve this particular issue you should go with:

```
@debits_for_rate.sum(&:amount)
```

Comment: Agreed above is inefficient; child of a slow do-a-little-step-n-verify  process.  Solved

Answer (score 1):

because your @debits_for_rate is an object not an array of numbers.

`@debits_for_rate.sum(&:amount)` 
else

`@debits_for_rate.map(&:amount).inject(:+)`

This will fetch you the sum.

Comment: Please remove your answer and edit @AndreyDeineko answer with `inject` code. Thanks

Comment: @ABPrime there is no need to edit my answer with `inject` because it is always more efficient to make singe traverse over an array than two (as here `map` and `inject`) :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: Agree.